# Combobox and textField inside a button?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to add one ***UITextField*** and one ***ComboBox*** inside a "location" button.
When the user taps on the "location" button the ***UITextField*** and the ***ComboBox*** should appear on the screen and when the user taps outside the "location" button, the ***UITextField*** and the ***ComboBox*** should get hidden.

How can I do this? Any tutorial or source code will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create a UIButton in the xib with custom style .Add UITextFiled and picker view which having default functionality of the combo box in iOS .Or you can make you custom combo box.Make both hidden by default

2.On click event of the button.

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender 
{
   textfield.hidden=NO;
   picker.hidden=NO;
   //do other logic whatever you want here.

}
```

for dismissing the picker and textfield:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
       textfield.hidden=NO;
       picker.hidden=NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your target an iPad? If so, try using UIPopverController. Here's the Apple docs on it:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Is your target an iPhone? If so, you might consider creating a second view controller to hold the desired controls and then calling **presentModalViewController** on the first view controller, like such:

```
[self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES]
```

You will also need some sort of "done" button and should use delegation to call back to the first view controller.

If you're new to delegation, see this tutorial (also gives example of presenting a view controller modally):

http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development

(By the way, please note that iOS doesn't really have a "combo box" option. However, there are alternatives such as UISegmentedControl or UIPickerView.)

Cheers!